# Emails getting delivered to promotions tab in gmail

Tags: tabs, gmail, promotions

We have a magento based portal which triggers welcome emails on user signing up. These welcome emails have a header image, some content with links for the users to access their account and a signature with a footer text and image.

The problem now is that these emails always seem to land in the promotion tab in gmail and not to the inbox. When we remove the header image, it seems to go the inbox.

Anyone has any idea how we go about how to fix the image that will make it go to the inbox? The promotion tab is virtually a black hole - no one reads those emails.

Comment: I think your question is off-topic because it seems to have nothing to do with programming

Comment: Sathish, Did you solved the issue? I'm searching for an answer to that too...

Comment: Yes. LudCI. It has nothing to do with Magento. Basically gmail has a algorithm to mark an email as promotional or not by scoring the emails based on subject, design, images, footer etc. We changed the design to make it come to the inbox. The less images better. Also avoid certain sales/marketing like words in the email content.